# Forbidden - You don't have permission to access on this server

Tags: git, apache

I recently cloned from git a customer website and i need to work on it but when i try to open it via mamp or ampps a message appears:

> Forbidden
>   You don't have permission to access "websitename"/application/index.html on this server.

I have done extensive research and everyone says to change the permission on `httpd.conf`, but nothing happened. I tried to reinstall it and nothing as well.
If I'm navigating via terminal into the folder of the website I have all the permissions.

Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: It has nothing todo with the httpd.conf folder but with the permissions/ownership of the path..

Comment: thanks, so what can be a solution for solve it??

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with permission so 
Try to run this from terminal

`chmod -R 775 project_folder`

if this doesn't work i believe `index.php` is not in the root directory maybe in `public` folder so make sure your `.htaccess` is redirecting requests there